# Xamarin Forms:Prism MVVM:Android:Navigate to specific page when click on Push Notification

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, prism

I am trying to implement a basic push notification example using
**Xamarin Forms with Prism MVVM, Azure & FCM**.

I am receiving notification, but couldn't navigate to a specific page when clicked on the notification.

Trying basic functionality when the app is running or in the background (not closed).

When click on notification, need to navigate to MainPage as shown in below code).

It is calling MainPage, but, not initializing ViewModel (MainPageViewModel).

I am not very sure, is this the right way of navigating from Android project.

Similar code worked fine in iOS.

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
     base.OnNewIntent(intent);
     Intent = intent;
     var page = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
     Prism.PrismApplicationBase.Current.MainPage = page;
}
```

Any hints, please...!

#### Updated.... Answer

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
     base.OnNewIntent(intent);
     Intent = intent;

     //var page = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
     //Prism.PrismApplicationBase.Current.MainPage = page;

     var container = (App.Current as Prism.Unity.PrismApplication).Container;
     var navigationService = container.Resolve<INavigationService>();
     navigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationPage/MainPage");
}
```

and added below registration in App.xaml.cs file

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.Register<Prism.Navigation.INavigationService, 
    Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService>();
}
```

Comment: On what version of android did you test?

Comment: I am testing using Nokia 8.1 which is on API 28 (PIE)

Comment: Apps that are running on Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher must create a notification channel for publishing their notifications.

Comment: @AbbyWang-MSFT I am receiving notifications, but had problem with navigating to a page.